# How can initialize bits of unsigned char?

Tags: visual-c++, binary

I want to initialize bits of a variable of unsigned char with a string of binary digits, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it seems like you want to parse an ASCII string of binary digits.  This is how you do that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
const char* binary = "10001001";
char* next;
unsigned char value = strtoul(binary, &next, 2);
if (*next) { /* conversion failed */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char s[] = "How now brown cow.\n";
```

Comment: thanks, i have a string like "10001001" and i want to store it in an unsigned char variable . How to do it?

Comment: @zahratTZ If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.